# wp7 ListBox/Advanced list like Native Mail client

Tags: email, windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone-7.1

I'm wondering how come the number of controls is limited to https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHBbz.png

I can not see how Mail's list is made. Can anyone shed some light on this?
Specifically, I'm wondering how I can have a list of items, and when clicked, show options beneath it (as with Mail's grouping of conversations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `ExpanderView` in the newest version of the [Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/71550).

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Looks exactly like what I need. Now to add the toolbox to visual studio :)